# How can I get credit inquiries bumped off my Equifax credit report?

Tags: credit, credit-report

I understand that there is a bug with Equifax such that if you pull your credit report enough times, you eventually will bump off older hard inquiries other than those for mortgages and cars.

Please explain how this 'bumpage' is done.

Thanks.

Comment: sounds as something with high potential to backfire and bring more trouble than good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it would be easier to wait.  Credit inquires don't make up such a large part of your score.

Pay your bills on time, don't have a ton of debt and your credit will heal quickly without trying to game the system.

Equifax is only one of three players, so anything you do to "fix" equifax is going to show up on the others.  *Bumping* inquires off of Equifax will just pollute Transunion and Experian.

Edit from JoeTaxpayer - You might consider signing up at [CreditKarma](http://www.creditkarma.com), a free service, it will let you see the inquiries in real time, and knowing they fall off after two years, you can track the impact to you score.

Comment: MrChrister wrote: "Equifax is only one of three players, so anything you do to "fix" equifax is going to show up on the others. Bumping inquires off of Equifax will just pollute Transunion and Experian."

OMG...I have never read such hog wash in my life!  Even if you do find a way to bump inq's off EQ, they are NOT going to suddenly show up on either of the other 2.  All 3 reporting agencies work totally independantly.  They do not consult each other, share info or compare your info on others sites with what they have for you on their own site.  They don't even use the same FICO scoring algo

Comment: @BungalowMo Please feel free to explain *bumping* and how what I said is hogwash.  I accept you might know more than me.  Make your case instead of being an Internet Tough Guy.  =)